# jqueryui droppable and sortable can work together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

i want drag an item into container.
and whether the item in or not in container,it both sortable,and you
can drag item out of container,the order is still correct.

but now when you drag an item into container,it can not drag it out
anymore.

[here is jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kingwrcy/bRbyW/1/)

```
anyone can help ? huge thanks!
```

Comment: no you cannot use both the things together you have to write your custom logic using jqueryui

Comment: @pareshm who told you ?

Comment: @melvin cause I tried the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the sortables into their own div and make it droppable too.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="item-list">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">container</div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$("#item-list, .container").sortable();
$("#item-list, .container").droppable({
    accept: ".item-container",
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass("item-container").addClass("item"));
        dropped.remove();
    }
});

$(".container").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass("item").addClass("item-container"));
        dropped.remove();
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.item, .item-container {
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    margin:10px 0;
    cursor:move;
}
```

Here is the **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bRbyW/3/

Comment: but the **container can not sort** anymore,i want container it self can sort as the same as the sortable item,anyway,thank you very much.

Comment: My mistake. If one list accepts items of some class and the other accepts items of another class, it will work. Otherwise they'll get mixed up.

Comment: thank u man,but there is still bug,i can not drag an item after container,and when i drag an item out from container,it will be the last one before container,can not move to other place,my final solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bRbyW/4/) ,the container is still can not sort,but i think the project manager will ignore this bug,thank u !